# In R how do I run a block of code in local environment while getting some variables from global environment

Tags: r

Here's a toy example:

```
{
   tmp_a <- a # a is some variable from Global Environment
   # do something with tmp_a
   a <<- tmp_a
}
```

What I want is essentially a function without function head. I want all of temporary variables created inside the block removed after the program exits this block. I don't want to do it in a function because this block is too long, and it access many global variables. Passing all the variables to the function can be much slower.

I also tried `local()`, but in that way it cannot access global variables anymore.

Comment: You should study the [scoping rules of R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Scope-of-variables) before proceeding any further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`local` can access variables outside it.  Below the `a` within `local` comes from the global environment and `tmp_a` is destroyed when local exits.

```
a <- 1
a <- local({
   tmp_a <- a
   tmp_a <- tmp_a + 1
   tmp_a
})
a
## [1] 2
exists("tmp_a")
## [1] FALSE
```

Note that this would have worked the same way so there is no real reason you can't use a function although `local` seems more appropriate here.

```
a <- 1
f <- function() {
   tmp_a <- a
   tmp_a <- tmp_a + 1
   tmp_a
}
a <- f()
a
## [1] 2
exists("tmp_a")
## [1] FALSE
```